# Weird grails error user error

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am using Grails with no database and with Spring Security LDAP. It was working fine, but suddenly is now doing

```
HTTP Status 500 - could not execute query;
SQL [select this_.id as id2_0_, this_.version as version2_0_, this_.account_expired as account3_2_0_, this_.account_locked as account4_2_0_, this_.enabled as enabled2_0_, this_."password" as password6_2_0_, this_.password_expired as password7_2_0_, this_.username as username2_0_ from user this_ where (this_.username=?)];
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Any idea where this comes from?  I have tried doing `grails clean` and doing `grails RefreshDependencies`.

Comment: Looks like it is trying to hit the DB when it shouldn't be. Have you set the following properties in Config.groovy `grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']` and `grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false`?

Comment: `grails.plugins.springsecurity` >> `grails.plugin.springsecurity`. plugins changed to plugin

Comment: True. Which version of spring security are you using?

Comment: Already have both of those as well as the rest of my config, I can share if it will help.  Was working before and suddenly stopped.  

spring secuirty core - 1.2.7.3
spring security ldap - 1.0.6